# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] error

Tags: android

I have an AVD emulator set at API 18 and my manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pushpindesigns.com.lines"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".mainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Level_1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_level_1" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Updated build.gradle file that includes the compilesdkversion = 18

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pushpindesigns.com.lines"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 'L'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Code above is updated and still doesn't work.................Let me know what you think

Comment: What is your Build SDK (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse, `compileSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` for Android Studio)?

Comment: It says 'android-L' Should i change this to like 18?

Comment: I haven't looked into it much yet but I don't think you can run any apps that have a target of 20 (android-L) on a device that doesn't have Android L installed.

Comment: Get the same error after changing it to 18 and my AVD is api 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `android-L` with something else -- `20` or `19` would be likely choices. The "L" Developer Preview will not work on anything but "L"-equipped devices and emulators.

Also, the `targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` overrides that which is in your manifest. Replace the `targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` to `20`.

Comment: @user3830363: Could you post your `build.gradle` file as an edit to your question?

Comment: Updated and added build.gradle